# java script Alerts Unicode display issue in IE 8

Tags: php, javascript, unicode, symfony1, internet-explorer-8

currently im working on symfony based large application. i m having issue on displaying unicode characters inside java script alerts in IE browsers only fire fox not a issue working fine

for example

```
alert("<?php echo __("English word to auto convert to other languages by symfony ")?>");
```

In IE 8 version i can only see boxes when alert pops up.

have anybody idea why this happen please.

regards

Comment: Can you post the unicode characters as well? Are they as generated as the character itself(`έ`) or as codes(`\u03AD`)? `alert("\u03AD")` works well, even in IE 7(on XP)

Comment: im using symfony helper function like this echo __("word"); then only this happen. as u said  alert("\u03AD") wroking fine. 

When i got the alert i can see some boxex on the popup message

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the page? And the encoding IE is detecting? (View -> encoding, see what is selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the encoding of the page. This should be in an encoding that supports unicode characters.

Comment: its working this was the issue   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta> put it to your index thats all thank you!