# MVC string encoding issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, character-encoding

I have some code like the following.

```
.... some jquery code here .....
var fullAddress = '@Model.AddressParseResult.normalizedAddress.ToString()';

alert(fullAddress);
.... some jquery code here .....
```

The value of the "normalizedAddress" is "içerenköy" (it has turkish letters). 
However in alert window i get the result like:

```
i&#231;erenk&#246;y
```

I think i am doing something wrong about chracter encoding. Any idea how can i get the correct string ?

Comment: There are additional browser / page encoding issues to be aware if you are trying to alert Unicode characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006376/java-script-alerts-unicode-display-issue-in-ie-8

Comment: `meta utf-8` have you included it?

Comment: Jai i have it already. anssi 's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.Raw` should put the correct encoding in place.

Answer (score 1):

exactly, you should use like this:

```
var address = '@Html.Raw(Model.AddressParseResult.normalizedAddress.ToString())';
```